# cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.SolverFoundation.Services.Term' to 'bool'

Tags: c#, ms-solver-foundation

I got an exception "cannot implicitly convert type 'Microsoft.SolverFoundation.Services.Term' to 'bool'" at the code below, how should I solve it?

```
Term a=null;
            if(a==null)//<--this line exception
            {

            }
```

Below is the snap shot

[image]

Comment: That sounds like a compile-time error rather than an exception... could you give more details?

Comment: Hi I am sure, and yes, this is compile-time error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the `Term` class overrides the equality operator in a way that it doesn't return bool but another `Term` instead: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff525374%28v=vs.93%29.aspx

I am not sure why they would do something like this, because it goes against any advice on overriding operators...

To fix your problem, use this code instead:

```
if(ReferenceEquals(a, null))
```

Comment: But this is really the case I am facing, double check, it is ==, and still give error.

Comment: hi, snapshot is in the question now

Comment: @william007: Forget the screenshot. I know what's up. Updating my answer.

Comment: One can also cast one (or both) sides of the `==` sign to `object`. When one operand if of type `object`, the user-defined overload doesn't apply. So instead of `(a == null)` use either `((object)a == null)` or `(a == (object)null)`.